Please help me show $P(a-W_n \leq V_n < a)\to 0$
setup
Suppose that $V_n \overset{L}{\to} H, W_n\overset{P}{\to}0$, and $a$ is a continuity point of $H$.
result
Then,
$$
P(a - W_n \leq V_n < a)\to 0.
$$
We want to show this.
my try
Under the assumptions, I find that
$$
V_n + W_n \overset{L}{\to} H.
$$
From the definition of convergence in law, it follows
$$
P(V_n + W_n \leq a) = 1 - P(V_n + W_n \geq a) \to H(a).
$$
Thus,
$$
P(a - W_n \leq V_n) \to 1 - H(a).
$$
On the other hand, it holds
$$
P(V_n \leq a) \to H(a).
$$
From above, we get
$$
P(a - W_n \leq V_n) + P(V_n < a) \to 1.
$$
However, the left side is not equal to $P(a - W_n \leq V_n < a)$.
How can I do this?

Note that $P(a-W_n \leq V_n < a, W_n \leq 0)=0$. So, let us introduce an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ and consider the following:
$P(a-W_n \leq V_n < a) = P(a - W_n \leq V_n < a, W_n > 0)$
$ = P(a - W_n \leq V_n < a,0 <  W_n \leq \epsilon) + P(a-W_n \leq V_n < a, W_n > \epsilon)$.
The first term above can be upper bounded by $P(a - \epsilon \leq V_n < a)$ and the second term can be upper bounded by $P(W_n > \epsilon)$.
If you first send $n$ to infinity, and then send $\epsilon$ to 0 (using the continuity of $H$ at $a$), you prove the result.
Edit: To provide more details: First, since $H$ is a cdf, there can only be a countable number of discontinuities. Therefore, we can find a sequence of $\epsilon_k>0$ such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \epsilon_k = 0$ and that $a-2\epsilon_k$ is a continuity point of $H$.
Now, for any fixed $\epsilon_k$, we have that
$P(W_n > \epsilon_k) \leq P(|W_n| > \epsilon_k) \rightarrow_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ by the definition of convergence in probability.
Also, for any fixed $\epsilon_k$, $P(a-\epsilon_k \leq V_n < a) \leq P(a-2 \epsilon_k < V_n \leq a) = P(V_n \leq a) - P(V_n \leq a-2\epsilon_k) \rightarrow_{n \rightarrow \infty} H(a) - H(a - 2\epsilon_k)$
by the definition of convergence in distribution and the fact that $a$ and $a - 2\epsilon_k$ are continuity points of $H$.
So, we have shown $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(a-W_n \leq V_n < a) \leq H(a) - H(a-2\epsilon_k)$. This holds for all $\epsilon_k$, so we can now send $k \rightarrow \infty$ and use the fact that $a$ is a continuity point of $H$ to conclude that $H(a) - H(a-2\epsilon_k) \rightarrow_{k \rightarrow \infty} 0$.

I understand the policy, but why is it $P(a-\epsilon\leq V_n<a)\to 0, P(W_n > \epsilon)\to 0$?

I just updated the answer to include more information, let me know if that helps.
